# Is this code taking the file weight from the site's traffic?

Tags: php, readfile, traffic

I have this code:

```
$_REQUEST['file'] = "www.xxx.com/file.exe"; //for exemple
header("Content-type: application/x-file-to-save");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_REQUEST['name']);
header('Content-Length: ' . $contentLength);

readfile($_REQUEST['file']);
```

Is it taking the file's size of the server's traffic?

EDIT:
I bought a web host plan, that said I have 200 GB monthly traffic.
I have this code in my site. Beside the PHP file's size, is the READFILE() effecting my monthly traffic? Because I use this code to download more than 200GB per month.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does "taking the file's size of the server's traffic" mean?

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? I don't understand it (maybe a typo or something?)

Comment: It's not calculating the correct value for `$contentLength`, that's for sure.

Comment: @nickb What do you mean? I see no calculation anywhere..

Comment: I'm calculating somewhere else...

Comment: I;m editing the question to make it clearer

Comment: Isn't this something you should ask the service provider instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your monthly traffic is *any* data going in and/or out.*
It does not matter *how* that traffic is generated, it counts either way.
Think of it as bits traveling through the network cable, that's what counts.
In your case, it will certainly add download traffic. If `$_REQUEST['file']` points to another server, so your server has to download the file first, it will also add upload traffic.

---

* You don't specify whether the limit is upload, download or combined...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your question is:

> Does using this page to download files count against my bandwidth?

And my answer would be almost certainly yes.